# django clone repo is not working

Tags: python, django, postgresql, git-clone

I clone a Django project from github. But when I ran the `python manage.py runserver` it showed the following errors. How to fix them?

```
    python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/human-inside/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/human-inside/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 303, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/home/human-inside/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/human-inside/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/home/human-inside/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 92, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/human-inside/Desktop/web_project/parsifal/settings.py", line 18, in <module>
    default = config('DATABASE_URL'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/decouple.py", line 198, in __call__
    return self.config(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/decouple.py", line 77, in __call__
    return self.get(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/decouple.py", line 64, in get
    raise UndefinedValueError('%s option not found and default value was not defined.' % option)
decouple.UndefinedValueError: DATABASE_URL option not found and default value was not defined.
```

The setting.py is here:

```
from django.conf.global_settings import TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS as TCP
from unipath import Path
import dj_database_url
from decouple import config, Csv
from mendeley import Mendeley

SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = config('CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE', default=True, cast=bool)
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = config('SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE', default=True, cast=bool)

PROJECT_DIR = Path(__file__).parent

DEBUG = config('DEBUG', default=False, cast=bool) 
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

DATABASES = {
    'default': dj_database_url.config(
      default = config('DATABASE_URL'))
}

ALLOWED_HOSTS = config('ALLOWED_HOSTS', cast=Csv())

ADMINS = (
    ('Vitor Freitas', 'vitorfs@gmail.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True

MEDIA_ROOT = PROJECT_DIR.parent.parent.child('media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
FILE_UPLOAD_TEMP_DIR = '/tmp/'
FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS = 0644
FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 33554432

STATIC_ROOT = PROJECT_DIR.parent.parent.child('static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    PROJECT_DIR.child('static'),
)

SECRET_KEY = config('SECRET_KEY')

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'parsifal.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'parsifal.wsgi.application'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    PROJECT_DIR.child('templates'),
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = TCP + (
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.humanize',

    'parsifal.reviews',
    'parsifal.reviews.planning',
    'parsifal.reviews.conducting',
    'parsifal.reviews.reporting',
    'parsifal.reviews.settings',
    'parsifal.account_settings',
    'parsifal.activities',
    'parsifal.authentication',
    'parsifal.blog',
    'parsifal.core',
    'parsifal.help',
    'parsifal.library',
    'parsifal.search',
)

LOGIN_URL = '/signin/'
LOGOUT_URL = '/signout/'

EMAIL_BACKEND = config('EMAIL_BACKEND', default='django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend')
EMAIL_FILE_PATH = PROJECT_DIR.parent.child('maildumps')
EMAIL_HOST = config('EMAIL_HOST')
EMAIL_PORT = config('EMAIL_PORT', cast=int)
EMAIL_HOST_USER = config('EMAIL_HOST_USER')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = config('EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD')
EMAIL_USE_TLS = config('EMAIL_USE_TLS', cast=bool)
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'Parsifal Team <noreply@parsif.al>'
EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX = '[Parsifal] '
SERVER_EMAIL = 'application@parsif.al'

MENDELEY_ID = config('MENDELEY_ID', cast=int)
MENDELEY_SECRET = config('MENDELEY_SECRET')
MENDELEY_REDIRECT_URI = config('MENDELEY_REDIRECT_URI')
MENDELEY = Mendeley(MENDELEY_ID, client_secret=MENDELEY_SECRET, redirect_uri=MENDELEY_REDIRECT_URI)

DROPBOX_APP_KEY = config('DROPBOX_APP_KEY')
DROPBOX_SECRET = config('DROPBOX_SECRET')
DROPBOX_REDIRECT_URI = config('DROPBOX_REDIRECT_URI')

ELSEVIER_API_KEY = config('ELSEVIER_API_KEY')

ABSOLUTE_URL_OVERRIDES = {
    'auth.user': lambda u: '/%s/' % u.username,
}
```

Comment: show your settings.py

Comment: I added it to the post. Check it.

Answer (score 0):

In your .env or .ini file you need to have DATABASE_URL defined:

```
 DATABASE_URL=mysql://myuser:mypassword@myhost/mydatabase
```

change to the following in settings.py:

```
from dj_database_url import parse as db_url

DATABASES = {
    'default': config('DATABASE_URL', cast=db_url),
}
```